# PayPal IPN Listener does not receive byte[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5, paypal-ipn

I have created and locally tested three separate approaches to IPN Listner in an ASP.NET MVC5 project that all works locally when using test html as suggested. While logging from server indicates that the IPN test always hits the IPN action of the controller, the byte array is always empty.

The result is INVALID because all that gets sent out strOut is the appended command. The site is hosted on GoDaddy. PayPal IPN log doesn't track IPN responses from the IPN tool, so server logging from the MVC project is all I have had to go on.

All have been adapted from example code:

Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public EmptyResult PayPalPaymentNotification(PayPalCheckoutInfo payPalCheckoutInfo)
{
    PayPalListenerModel model = new PayPalListenerModel();
    model._PayPalCheckoutInfo = payPalCheckoutInfo;
    _logger.Info("payPalCheckoutInfo {0}", payPalCheckoutInfo);

    byte[] parameters = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Request.ContentLength);

    _logger.Info("PayPal/PayPalPaymentNotification Line 47 Request.ContentLength {0}", Request.ContentLength);

    if (parameters != null)
    {
        model.GetStatus(parameters);
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

PayPalCheckoutInfo.cs

```
public class PayPalCheckoutInfo
{
    //ipnguide.pdf - page 43
    #region "Transaction and Notification-Related Variables"
    /// use this to verify its not spoofed, this is our info
    public string receiver_email { get; set; } //127
    public string receiver_id { get; set; } //13
    /// Keep this ID to avoid processing the transaction twice
    /// The merchant’s original transaction identification number for the payment from the buyer, against which the case was registered.
    public string txn_id { get; set; }
    /// The kind of transaction for which the IPN message was sent.
    public string txn_type { get; set; }
    /// Encrypted string used to validate the authenticity of the transaction
    public string verify_sign { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region "Buyer Information Variables"

    public string address_country { get; set; } //64
    public string address_city { get; set; } //40
    public string address_country_code { get; set; }  //2
    public string address_name { get; set; } //128 - prob don't need
    public string address_state { get; set; } //40
    public string address_status { get; set; }  //confirmed/unconfirmed
    public string address_street { get; set; } //200
    public string address_zip { get; set; } //20
    public string contact_phone { get; set; } //20
    public string first_name { get; set; } //64
    public string last_name { get; set; } //64
    public string payer_email { get; set; } //127
    public string payer_id { get; set; }  //13

    public int? Zip
    {
        get
        {
            int temp;
            if (int.TryParse(address_zip, out temp))
            {
                return temp;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region "Payment Information Variables"

    /*
    public string auth_amount { get; set; }
    public string auth_exp { get; set; } //28
    public string auth_id { get; set; } //19
    public string auth_status { get; set; }
     */

    /// Token passed back from PayPal for cross ref
    public string token { get; set; }
    //public string checkoutstatus { get; set; }
    public string PayerID { get; set; }
    /// Passthrough variable you can use to identify your Invoice Number for this purchase. If omitted, no variable is passed back.
    public string invoice { get; set; } //127
    /// Item name as passed by you, the merchant. Or, if not passed by you, as
    /// entered by your customer. If this is a shopping cart transaction, PayPal
    /// will append the number of the item (e.g., item_name1, item_name2,
    /// and so forth).
    public string item_name1 { get; set; } //127
    public string item_number1 { get; set; } //127
    public string mc_currency { get; set; } //currency of the payment.
    public string mc_fee { get; set; } //Transaction fee associated with the payment
    public string mc_gross { get; set; }    //Full amount of the customer's payment 
    /// Whether the customer has a verified PayPal account.
    /// verified – Customer has a verified PayPal account
    /// unverified – Customer has an unverified PayPal account.
    public string payer_status { get; set; }
    /// HH:MM:SS Mmm DD, YYYY PDT (28chars)
    public string payment_date { get; set; }

    public DateTime TrxnDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(payment_date, out dt))
            {
                return dt;
            }
            else
            {
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    /// The status of the payment:
    /// Canceled_Reversal: A reversal has been canceled. For example, you
    /// won a dispute with the customer, and the funds for the transaction that was
    /// reversed have been returned to you.
    /// Completed: The payment has been completed, and the funds have been added successfully to your account balance
    ///Created: A German ELV payment is made using Express Checkout. Denied: You denied the payment. This happens only if the payment was
    /// previously pending because of possible reasons described for the pending_reason variable or the Fraud_Management_Filters_x variable.
    /// Expired: This authorization has expired and cannot be captured.
    ///Failed: The payment has failed. This happens only if the payment was made from your customer’s bank account.
    ///Pending: The payment is pending. See pending_reason for more information.
    ///Refunded: You refunded the payment.
    ///Reversed: A payment was reversed due to a chargeback or other type of reversal. The funds have been removed from your account balance and
    ///returned to the buyer. The reason for the reversal is specified in the ReasonCode element.
    ///Processed: A payment has been accepted.
    ///Voided: This authorization has been voided.
    public string payment_status { get; set; }
    /// echeck: This payment was funded with an eCheck.
    /// instant: This payment was funded with PayPal balance, credit card, or Instant Transfer.
    public string payment_type { get; set; }
    /// This variable is set only if payment_status = Pending. - too many reasons (look it up in pdf)
    public string pending_reason { get; set; }
    public string protection_eligibility { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string reason_code { get; set; }
    public string correlationID { get; set; }
    public string ack { get; set; }
    public string errmsg { get; set; }
    public int? errcode { get; set; }

    /// should hold the clientid passed in from setexpresscheckout
    public string custom { get; set; }

    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            decimal amount = 0;
            if (decimal.TryParse(mc_gross, out amount))
            {
                return amount;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public decimal Fee
    {
        get
        {
            decimal amount = 0;
            if (decimal.TryParse(mc_fee, out amount))
            {
                return amount;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

PayPalListenerModel:

```
public class PayPalListenerModel //: BaseModel
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public PayPalCheckoutInfo _PayPalCheckoutInfo { get; set; }

    public void GetStatus(byte[] parameters)
    {

        //verify the transaction             
        string status = Verify(true, parameters);

        if (status == "VERIFIED")
        {
            _logger.Info("PayPalListenerModel Line 24 - Verified");
            //check that the payment_status is Completed                 
            if (_PayPalCheckoutInfo.payment_status.ToLower() == "completed")
            {

                //check that txn_id has not been previously processed to prevent duplicates                      

                //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email                                          

                //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct                       

                //process payment/refund/etc                     

            }
            else
            {
                _logger.Info("PayPalListenerModel Line 40 - Payment Status Not == completed {0}", _PayPalCheckoutInfo.payment_status);

            }
        }
        else if (status == "INVALID")
        {
            _logger.Info("PayPalListenerModel Line 46 - Status == INVALID");
            //log for manual investigation             
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Info("PayPalListenerModel Line 51  from line 24 Not ==  VALID or INVALID");
            //log response/ipn data for manual investigation             
        }



    }

    private string Verify(bool isSandbox, byte[] parameters)
    {

        string response = "";
        try
        {

            string url = isSandbox ?
              "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" : "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

            _logger.Info("Verify Method - Line 71 Url {0}", url);

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            //must keep the original intact and pass back to PayPal with a _notify-validate command
            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(parameters);
            data += "&cmd=_notify-validate";

            webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

            //Send the request to PayPal and get the response                 
            using (StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                streamOut.Write(data);
                _logger.Info("Validate Method Line 87 Streamout to PayPAl {0} ", data);
                streamOut.Close();
            }

            using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
                streamIn.Close();
                _logger.Info("Validate Method Line 95 Stream IN from PayPal ", response);
            }

        }
        catch { }

        return response;

    }
} 
}
```

-GoDaddy Server Logs:

```
-2015-02-13 09:06:28 W3SVC1322 P3NWVPWEB016 192.186.207.164 GET                    ---/PayPal/PayPalNotification token=EC-0BX962673U222251L&PayerID=ARX4U24K27RUU        443 -- 73.50.103.48 HTTP/1.1      Mozilla/5.0+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+--    (KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/41.0.2272.53+Safari/537.36 -    SP.NET_SessionId=bit34j4u4ussju21te4it1wk;+token=6daf747f-598e-4151-9fae-    07486a4939ba;+__RequestVerificationToken=xX7uLN0VIn5XsM6Ri9uSw9_THe1hxyYna53HMnu    IqkS9inMujdX004A-sJcQTVCs8mqGnqrqcefHaFVzk4ITiKDGcoNWuukvFvl88zDtj0c1 -      niaspringconference.com 404 0 0 2193 683 93
```

NLog Application Logs:

```
RegistrationGroups Conteroller Save Changes RegistrationGroupId 15
payPalCheckoutInfo NIAC.PayPalCheckoutInfo
PayPal/PayPalPaymentNotification Line 47 Request.ContentLength 0
Verify Method - Line 71 Url https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
Validate Method Line 87 Streamout to PayPAl &cmd=_notify-validate 
Validate Method Line 95 Stream IN from PayPal 
 PayPalListenerModel Line 46 - Status == INVALID
```